# How to move the text to top left instead of the bottom left corner in a openlayers feature?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers, openlayers-6, openlayers-5

```
addLabelBox(labelBoxData) {
        const newFeature = new Feature(this.feature.getGeometry());

        const textStyle = new Style({
            fill: new Fill({
                color: 'rgba(162, 72, 87, 1)'
            }),
            stroke: new Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
                width: 2
            }),
            text: new Text({
                text: labelBoxData.text,
                font: '12px sans-serif',
                fill: new Fill({ color: '#fff' }),
                placement: 'line',
                textBaseline: 'bottom',
                textAlign: 'left'
            })
        });

        // Set the style for the new feature
        newFeature.setStyle(textStyle);

        this.labelBoxesLayer.getSource().addFeature(newFeature);
    }
```

I am using this function to create a rectangular feature along with the text but the issue I am facing is that the text is rendered in bottom left corner instead of the top left corner as shown in the image.  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THe9k.png)

I have played with all the possible combinations of 'placement' and 'textBaseline' but unable to do it. Also, if the length of the text is longer than the box then the text disappears instead of the text breaking into multiple lines. I am using a textarea element to add the text. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It do notthink you can choose which face of the polygon line placement uses.  Instead you could separate the text into a separate style and set a point geometry for it

```
const textStyle = [
  new Style({
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'rgba(162, 72, 87, 1)
    }),
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
      width: 2
    }),
  }),
  new Style({
    geometry: function (feature) {
      return new Point(getTopLeft(feature.getGeometry().getExtent()));
    },
    text: new Text({
      text: labelBoxData.text,
      font: '12px sans-serif',
      fill: new Fill({color: '#fff'}),
      placement: 'point',
      textBaseline: 'top',
      textAlign: 'left'
    }),
  })
];
```

Comment: The issue with this is that if the text is long it will always stay in a single line and overflow out of the box instead of staying inside the box and moving to the second line.

Comment: There is no automatic wrapping of text in OpenLayers.  You need to use a stringDivider function such as the simple one in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-labels.html or wrapText in https://github.com/openlayers/ol-mapbox-style/blob/main/src/text.js#L41